# Laravel: Two Actions in a Form - one with "on-change" one with a button?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

in my Laravel App I have a Blade "Insert Project" where I want to dynamic load html data from Database when a DropDown changes. To be more concrete: I have several Project Categories in the Table "Cats" (id, name, code) - Each Category needs different fields to be added, therefore I have put the html code in the Table "Cats". I want to achieve the following:

If a user selects a Project Category the html code which is attached to the category should be shown.

My Code so far:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('project-insert') }}">
                  @csrf
                  <form action="{{ route('filter') }}" method="post">
                    <label for="Cat">Kategorie</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="cat_id" id="cat_id" data-parsley-required="true" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
                            @foreach ($cats as $sn)
                              {
                                  <option value="{{ $sn->id }}">{{ $sn->name }}</option>
                                  }
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                      </form>
<div class="form-group row mb-0">
                        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                {{ __('Add Project') }}
                            </button>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </form>
```

In my Controller I have add:

```
  public function insertProject(Request $data) {

    return $data['cat_id'];

}

public function filter(Request $request)
{
  $cat_id = $request->input("cat_id");
  return $cat_id;
  $code = DB::table('cats')->where('id', '=', $cat_id);

  var_dump($code->code);
}
```

When I change the DropDown, then the function "insertProject" will be called and not the desired function "filter".

How can I achieve it to call the correct function, or how can I achieve it to  call "insertProject" only when the button has been pressed?

Thank you for your advice and help.

Stefan

Comment: I don't think that's possible to put a Form inside another one, instead you can load that by javascript or add a specific param to the route and then check by that param.

Comment: This is not possible, you are declaring forms within Forms, so this wont get triggered always in a way that you intend, you need to change your HTML.

Comment: A one liner to test this is to remove the 2nd Form, as practically there is no insert button there, and i dont see a reason for having a Form there, since you dont wanna trigger its action

Comment: You can give a name attribute to each button and act accordingly when one is submitted. The unclicked button will be absent in POST data.